# Newbie; Ember modal for create record

Tags: javascript, ember.js, modal-dialog, semantic-ui

I'm working on an app, and trying to figure out ember.

I have followed this: http://ember.guru/2014/master-your-modals-in-ember-js to getting my modals working, and I have no problem getting edit and delete to work, but I can't figure out how to get create working.

here is my link for **edit**:

```
<a {{action 'showModal' 'contact.addresses.modal' contactAdress}}><i class="pencil circular icon"></i></a>
```

and for **create**:

```
<div class="ui button small" {{action 'showModal' 'contact.addresses.new' ##WHAT TO PUT HERE##}}><i class="plus icon"></i> New Address</div>
```

my router for the section

```
this.resource('contact', {path: '/contact/:contact_id'}, function(){
    this.route('personage', {path: '/'});
    this.route('addresses');
    ...
```

the addresses is a belongs_to to contacts

Can someone please point me in the right direction, I have worked on this for days now!

**UPDATE**

**route: contact.addresses.new**

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller) {
        controller.set('fields', {})
    }
});
```

Comment: I have created the following controller:contact.adresses.new and the route for it as well.

Comment: You don't have a `contact.addresses.new` route.

Comment: Yes I have, i'll post it in the question.

Comment: No, I mean that route does not exist in your router. Based on the router you have shown us, you have 4 custom routes: `contact`, `contact.index`, `contact.personage` and `contact.addresses`. There is no `contact.addresses.new` route.

Comment: like this? `this.resource('adresses', function(){ this.route('new'); });`

Comment: Yes, you would need something like that. And now, more importantly, why do you require a model for a `new` route? You don't have a model, the whole point of the route is to _create a model_.

Comment: I added that route, after working on this problem for hours, because I dont now what to do right now :) Pretty new to this Ember Js.

Comment: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xabeb/1/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the nested resources, you can use the route with last parts.

see more : http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_nested-resources